# Dataframe use grouped row values as a row name

Tags: python, pandas

i just started to work with python (`pandas`) and now i have my first question.
I have a dataframe with the following row names:

```
ID  A    Class
1  True  [0,5]
2  False [0,5]
3  True  [5,10]
4  False [10,20]
5  True  [0,5]
6  False [10,20]
```

Now i'm looking for a cool solution, where i can do something like this:

```
Class  True   False
[0,5]   2      1
[5,10]  1      0
[10,20] 0      2
```

I want to count how much `True` and `False` i have for a `Class`
Is there a fast solution? My Dataframe could have more than 2 million entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataframe, I would first use:

```
g = df.groupby('Class')['A'].value_counts().reset_index()
```

that returns:

```
     Class      A  0
0    [0,5]   True  2
1    [0,5]  False  1
2  [10,20]  False  2
3   [5,10]   True  1
```

then I would pivot the above table to get your desired shape:

```
a = pd.pivot_table(g, index='Class', columns='A', values=0).fillna(0)
```

This returns:

```
A        False  True 
Class                
[0,5]      1.0    2.0
[10,20]    2.0    0.0
[5,10]     0.0    1.0
```

Comment: If type of 'Class' is a list and not a string, this throws unhashable type exception.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Does it occur in the case of the other answer as well?

Comment: It does. About to comment.

Comment: Thank you guys, it helped me to solve my problem. I got an unexpected keyword argument 'index', so i needed to change it to this:

a = pd.pivot_table(g, rows='Class', cols='level_1', values=0).fillna(0)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to do the aggregation. After that, it's just a matter of formatting the column names and index to match your desired output.

```
# Perform the pivot and aggregation.
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Class', columns='A', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

# Format column names and index to match desired output.
df.columns = [c[1] for c in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The resulting output:

```
     Class  False  True
0    [0,5]      1     2
1  [10,20]      2     0
2   [5,10]      0     1
```

**Edit:**

The above solution assumes that the elements of the `'Class'` column are strings.  If they are lists, you could do the following:

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].map(tuple)
**original solution code here**
df['Class'] = df['Class'].map(list)
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work on Python 2.7 & pandas 0.18.0. It works with `aggfunc=len` though.

Comment: That's odd.  Works for me on Python 3.5 & Pandas 0.18.0.

Comment: It returns a dataframe with only the index - no counts. An issue about how True/False values are handled maybe?

Comment: @ayhan Another data point: I just tested the solution with Python 2.7 & Pandas 0.17.0 and it worked for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/s3geIRY.png I tried with string A column, named index etc but didn't work. A bug related to my environment I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @ayhan Can you try it with `ID` as an actual column, and not as the index?  I assumed that it was a column in my code, as it has a name and starts at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Yeah it is working now. It seems it returned an empty dataframe as there was no column to count. Strange that it works with `len` function though.